# Can anyone identify my early 90s BMX

Tags: identify-this-bike, bmx

This BMX is around 25-30 years old, I had it as a kid and was always respraying and changing parts (easy to remove parts, mainly seats and brakes) It eventually was left to rust in the shed until, during lockdown, To kill some time in evenings, I decided to clean it up sand it down and respray it, just wondering if anyone knows what model it is, located in Ireland.

Thanks for looking

[image]

Comment: Something generic. What kind of identification do you need? The manufacturer brand? Are the wheels original? What other parts are original?

Comment: Hi, thanks for looking, the wheels, frame, fork, handlebars are all original, the brand of wheel is simplex, a few search’s and looking at other threads , simplex seem to be a cheaper wheel used, the pedals are new, The old ones were metal ones that cut up your shin if you missed the pedal 

Comment: Sorry, not looking for massive information just curious to manufacturers brand and maybe how old it actually is as i was the second owner of the bike

Comment: Aside - that seat post looks bent already - you're older and wiser and probably somewhat heavier than you used to be.  So do be mindful of the long stick-out of seat post.

Comment: The only thing notable is that detail between the head tube and the down tube.  Otherwise it's generic BMX.

Answer (score 1):

I've looked back at some of the BMX types of my youth years and recall there weren't many Skyway wheels with as many plastic spokes, ie, 7.

This may be your best search technique if the bike is totally original to when new.

Also another rare feature is the small triangular inserted section on the underside of the frame positioned near to the Head-tube&fork tube section...

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Great stuff - thank you.

Comment: I'll get the hang of the workings of the group eventually..Thing is that you have to learn by your mistakes..

Comment: don't worry - My first answer was quite dreadful.  I now find it helpful to re-read the question several times while writing the answer, to keep on track.

Comment: Cheers thanks for the reassurance lol

Answer (score 0):

I used to have a Raleigh ultra burner and my mate a super tuff burner don't look like any of them   but my mate had 1 with a pedal back brake similar to yours does this have a similar rear brake? Think it might of been a Mongoose or a Scott bmx.

Comment: Possibly a Peugeot or Diamondback.

Comment: Practically every BMX made in that era had coaster brakes.

Comment: My Raleigh ultra, mate's Super Tuff and most of my mates wasn't.  There was one in around 10 of our bikes.

Comment: BMX bikes often have front rim brakes, to meet legal requirements for two sets of brakes in some jurisdictions.  But the rear brakes are generally coaster, except on hoity-toity bikes.